# "More than one person a day is/are killed"

Tags: verb-agreement

If I wrote a sentence saying "More than one person a day _______ killed by these massacres," would the blank be replaced by is or are?

Answer (score -1):

"More than one"=2 or more and takes the plural "are."

Comment: That would be logical, but it doesn't seem to be conventional. Could you back this up with a source or further explanation?